# Leaflet click event not working on iPad

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm using the angular leaflet directive. Everything is working properly on my laptop. But on iPad, the double click is working but the click event is not working at all. I have one event handler for click but it doesn't get triggered.

```
    $scope.events = {
      map: {
        enable: ['mousedown', 'dblclick', 'click'],
        logic: 'broadcast'
      }
    };

    $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.mousedown', function(event) {
      alert('click');
    });

    $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.click', function(event) {
      alert('click');
    });      

    $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.dblclick', function(event) {
      alert('dbclick');
    });
```

Double click event gets triggered but the other ones not. Anything I can try to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

checkout this  https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1300.
Having this below code fixed that issue for us,

`$mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();`

Comment: Are you using material design also?